# Como fazer o usuário retornar a condição especificada quando o mesmo digitar errado?

Tags: python, lista, while

Em Python, quando o usuário digitar uma opção inexistente, como faço para pedir que ele digite novamente uma das opções desejadas?

> Fazer um programa onde o usuário possa digitar vários valores
>   numéricos e cadastre-os em uma lista.
>
> Caso o número já exista lá dentro, ele não será adicionado.
>
> No final será exibido todos os valores únicos digitados em uma ordem
>   crescente.

Segue abaixo o programa que estou criando:

```
numeros=[]

while True:
    numeros.append(int(input('Digite um número: ')))
    condicao=str(input('Deseja continuar? SIM ou NÃO? ')).upper()

    if condicao=='NÃO':
        numeros.sort()
        unicos=list(set(numeros))
        #O comando  list(set(lista))  faz com que os números repetidos digitados não se repitam.
        print(f'Os números digitados (excluindo os duplicados) foram {unicos}')
        break

    elif condicao!='SIM':
    # Como faço para fazer o usuário retornar a "condicao" SIM ou NÃO?
        print('Essa opção não existe. Tente de novo.')
```

Comment: O código não estão bom, mas parece fazer o que deseja, ou não? Se não, então favor explicar melhor o que está querendo.

Comment: Preciso que, quando o usuário caia na condição "SIM" ou "NÃO", e erroneamente digite algo que não seja nenhuma dessas duas opções, quero que ele retorne a condição até digitar "SIM" ou "NÃO".

Comment: If-Elif-Else, pronto https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Comment: Sim, e parece que é isto que seu código está fazendo, se não diga o que está errado e oque quer que ajude.

Comment: Quando coloco o programa para executar e o usuário digita algo diferente de "SIM" ou "NÃO" o programa retorna para o usuário digitar um número ao invés de retornar  novamente as condições "SIM" ou "NÃO". O que eu queria saber é um meio de fazer o usuário, caso ele digite errado, repetir a operação até digitar certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem algumas maneiras de resolver isto, uma delas seria assim:

```
numeros = []
while True:
    numeros.append(int(input('Digite um número: ')))
    while True:
        condicao = str(input('Deseja continuar? SIM ou NÃO? ')).upper()
        if condicao == 'SIM' or condicao == 'NAO': break
        print('Essa opção não existe. Tente de novo.')
    if condicao == 'NAO': break
numeros.sort()
unicos = list(set(numeros))
#O comando  list(set(lista))  faz com que os números repetidos digitados não se repitam.
print(f'Os números digitados (excluindo os duplicados) foram {unicos}')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yjRFki). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/LoopValidInput). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/LoopValidInput.py).

Assim você isola a repetição só desta parte, um laço é diferente do outro, eles devem repetir trechos diferentes de forma independente. Melhorei alguma organização, mas não consertei outros possíveis problemas.

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja implementar um programa que `monte` uma lista formada por números `inteiros` sem `repetições` e, no final, os exiba em ordem `crescente`. Pois bem, o código abaixo faz `tudo` isso.

```
from time import sleep

cont = 0
numeros = list()
continuar = True
while continuar == True:
    cont += 1
    if cont == 1:
        pa = 'algum'
    else:
        pa = 'outro'

    resp = input(f'Desejas digitar {pa} número? [S/N] ').strip()
    while resp not in 'SsNn':
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas "S" ou "N"!\033[m')
        resp = input(f'Desejas digitar {pa} número? [S/N] ').strip()

    if (resp == 'S') or (resp == 's'):
        while True:
            try:
                n = int(input(f'Digite o {cont}º número: '))
                break
            except:
                print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

        while n in numeros:
            print('\033[31mValor REPETIDO! Digite outro valor!\033[m')
            n = int(input(f'Digite o {cont}º número: '))
        numeros.append(n)

        continuar = True

    else:
        numeros.sort()
        print(f'\033[32mA lista gerada foi: {numeros}\033[m')
        print(f'\033[31mEncerrando o Programa!')
        for c in range(35):
            sleep(0.1)
            print(f'{chr(46)}', end='')
        continuar = False
        break
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/yuhizyhx-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Observe que este programa possui alguns tratamentos de valores.

1. Primeiro, ele verifica se o valor digitado é ou não um `inteiro`;
2. Segundo, ele verifica se o valor `inteiro` está ou não contido na `lista`.

Observe que o programa só permite a inserção dos valores, caso o valor seja, `inteiro` e `ainda não exista` na lista. Caso contrário, proíbe sua inserção.