# Como Reiniciar Um Programa Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho que fazer um programa que calcule a soma finita de uma progressão geométrica, então fiz:

```
a_1 = float(input('Primeiro Termo: '))
a_2 = float(input('Segundo Termo: '))
n = int(input('Número do Termo: '))
q = a_2 / a_1
a_n = (a_1) * (q) ** (n - 1)
S_n = a_1 * (q ** n - 1) / (q - 1)
print('a{} é igual à \033[1;31m{:.0f}\033[m'.format(n, a_n))
print('A soma dos {} primeiros termos da P.G. é igual à \033[1;31m{:.0f}\033[m'.format(n, S_n))
```

O problema é que eu gostaria de transformar ele em um executável, e toda vez que o programa acaba de rodar, ele simplesmente fecha, e isso é bem chato quando tenho que fazer mais de uma conta.
Então gostaria de dar uma opção ao usuário: **1** Realizar outra conta, **2** Fechar o programa.

Quando o usuário quisesse realizar outra conta, o programa reiniciaria e ele poderia fazer outra conta. Tentei com:

```
import sys
import os
def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

E Então:

```
print('[ 1 ] Realizar outra conta\n[ 2 ] Sair do Programa')
cu = int(input('Sua escolha: '))
if cu == 2:
    exit()
elif cu == 1:
    restart_program()
#Sim, com uma variável muito madura
```

Porém não funcionou :(
Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Isso não faz sentido, faça um `while`https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/352398/10 ou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385771/101.

Comment: Achei engraçado o nome da sua variável.

Comment: @Danizavtz será que CU = Choose User, ou Command User?

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa implementar um laço de repetição. Neste caso, a melhor forma é utilizar o `while`.

Para esta questão implementei o seguinte algoritmo...

```
while True:
    a_1 = float(input('Primeiro Termo: '))
    a_2 = float(input('Segundo Termo: '))
    n = int(input('Número do Termo: '))
    q = (a_2 / a_1)
    a_n = (a_1 * q ** (n - 1))
    S_n = (a_1 * (q ** n - 1)) / (q - 1)
    print('O {}º termo é igual à \033[1;31m{:.0f}\033[m'.format(n, a_n))
    print('A soma dos {} primeiros termos da P.G. é igual à \033[1;31m{:.0f}\033[m'.format(n, S_n))

    resp = input('Desejas continuar? [S/N] ').upper()
    while (len(resp) != 1) or (resp not in 'SN'):
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas "S" ou "N"!\033[m')
        resp = input('Desejas continuar? [S/N] ').upper()
    if resp == 'N':
        break
```

Observe neste algoritmo que quem controla o fluxo da digitação dos valores é o `primeiro` while. O segundo while serve para tratar a resposta do usuário. Se a resposta do usuário for `S` o algoritmo será novamente executado. Caso contrário o algoritmo será encerrado.

Answer (score 1):

Se quer que algo se repita várias vezes, não invente, use um *loop*. Uma versão bem simples seria:

```
while True:
    # faz o que precisa aqui (lê os números, faz as contas, etc)

    if input('Quer continuar? (S/N) ') == 'N':
        break
```

As outras respostas usam uma variável para controlar a condição do *loop*, mas nesse caso eu acho desnecessário. O valor digitado no último `input` só vai ser usado ali, para saber se deve continuar ou não, e depois não será usado para mais nada. Se digitar `N`, o `break` interrompe o *loop*.

Claro que você poderia fazer algo como:

```
condicao = True
while condicao:
    # faz o que precisa aqui (lê os números, faz as contas, etc)

    if input('Quer continuar? (S/N) ') == 'N':
        condicao = False
```

Mas eu acho mais simples fazer o `break`, que deixa claro que naquele ponto o *loop* deve ser interrompido.

---

Outro detalhe é que se digitar qualquer coisa que não seja "N", o `while` continua. Se quiser ser mais específico e só aceitar determinados valores, pode fazer isso separadamente:

```
while True:
    # faz o que precisa aqui (lê os números, faz as contas, etc)

    while True: # outro loop só para validar a opção
        opcao = input('Quer continuar? (S/N) ')
        if opcao not in ('S', 'N'):
            print('Digite apenas S ou N')
        else:
            break # sai do while interno
    if opcao == 'N':
        break # sai do while externo
```

Ou seja, outro *loop* só para ficar pedindo para digitar de novo, caso não seja uma das opções válidas. Repare que agora faz sentido ter uma variável para guardar a opção, pois vou usá-la mais de uma vez (para testar se é um dos valores válidos, e depois para ver se é a opção que encerra o programa).

---

Claro que aí dá pra sofisticar o quanto quiser/precisar. Se pesquisar por aí, vai ver que "muita gente" chama [`upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) para transformar a string em maiúscula (assim poderia ser digitado "n" ou "N", por exemplo), ou ainda `input(...)[0]` para pegar somente o primeiro caractere (isso tem uma falha, que é no caso do usuário digitar apenas <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, pois aí `input` retorna a string vazia e ao tentar acessar o primeiro caractere dará erro).

Se quiser, separe a leitura da opção em uma função específica:

```
def ler_opcao(mensagem, valores_validos = ['S', 'N']):
    validos = "/".join(valores_validos)
    while True:
        opcao = input(f'{mensagem} ({validos}) ')
        if opcao not in valores_validos:
            print(f'Digite apenas um dos valores válidos: {validos}')
        else:
            return opcao

while True:
    # faz o que precisa aqui (lê os números, faz as contas, etc)

    if ler_opcao('Quer continuar?') == 'N':
        break
```

Assim, a função `ler_opcao` recebe a mensagem e a lista de valores válidos (e a mensagem já mostrará esses valores com base na lista). Desta forma, você pode customizar à vontade. Por exemplo, se quiser que as opções sejam 1, 2 ou 3:

```
while True:
    # faz o que precisa aqui (lê os números, faz as contas, etc)

    opcao = ler_opcao('Digite 1 para fazer X, 2 para fazer Y, 3 para sair', ['1', '2', '3'])
    if opcao == '1':
        print('fazer X')
    elif opcao == '2':
        print('fazer Y')
    elif opcao == '3':
        break
```

Repare que nesse caso eu não preciso usar `int` para transformar a opção em número, pois se não for digitado um número, ele não estará entre as opções válidas. E nesse caso também faz sentido ter uma variável porque ela é usada várias vezes depois, para testar qual dos valores foi digitado.

---

No seu caso específico, então seria:

```
while True:
    # faz o que precisa aqui (lê os números, faz as contas, etc)

    if ler_opcao('[ 1 ] Realizar outra conta\n[ 2 ] Sair do Programa', ['1', '2']) == '2':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa para resolver este problema é colocar seu código dentro da função `restart_program`, segue um exemplo:

```
def restart_program():
    a_1 = float(input('Primeiro Termo: '))
    a_2 = float(input('Segundo Termo: '))
    n = int(input('Número do Termo: '))
    q = a_2 / a_1
    a_n = (a_1) * (q) ** (n - 1)
    S_n = a_1 * (q ** n - 1) / (q - 1)
    print('a{} é igual à \033[1;31m{:.0f}\033[m'.format(n, a_n))
    print('A soma dos {} primeiros termos da P.G. é igual à \033[1;31m{:.0f}\033[m'.format(n, S_n))

cu = ''
while cu != '2':
    restart_program()
    print('[ qualquer tecla ] Realizar outra conta\n[ 2 ] Sair do Programa')
    cu = input('Sua escolha: ')
```

Nesta solução reaproveitei o seu código para efetuar o comportamento esperado. ùnica coisa é que agora eu leio uma string ao inves de fazer um cast para o número 2, e eu leio qualquer valor para o cara poder reiniciar, caso queira utilizar os valores da pergunta, basta modificar o código.

Observe que nesta solução não é necessário utilizar as funções `sys` e `os`, pois caso o usuário selecione a opção '2' (string) , então já ocorre a condição para saída do laço.